# How do I use radio as component multiple times in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, data-visualization

I made a switch components in vue.
And this switch component emits the data selected to its parent template as below.

switchform.vue
**template**

```
<div :class = "{ 'switch-field' : !smallSelection,
                 'small-switch-field':smallSelection}"
 v-if='twoSelection'>

    <input type="radio" id="radio-first" name="switch-first" 
    @change="categoryChange"
    :value="options[0]" 
    v-model='selected'
    />
    <label for="radio-first">{{options[0].toUpperCase()}}</label>

    <input type="radio" id="radio-second" name="switch-second" 
    @change="categoryChange"
    :value="options[1]" 
    v-model='selected'
    />
    <label for="radio-second">{{options[1].toUpperCase()}}</label>
</div>
```

**methods**

```
methods:{
    categoryChange(){
        this.$emit("selectedCategory", this.selected);
    }
},
```

However, when I use this components twice in one view,
the two different button ui components conveys same data.

**parent**

```
<div class='main-body'>
    <div class='ticket-count-analysis'>
        <div class='analysis-title'>
            <div style='flex-grow:1'>Type of tickets</div>
            <div class='hr-line white'></div>
        </div>
        <div>{{currentRatioCategory}}</div>
        <switch-form
        :options='options'
        :smallSelection=false
        @selectedCategory='changeTypeCategory'
        class='option-switch'
        ></switch-form>
    </div>
    <div class='ticket-ratio-analysis'>
        <div class='analysis-title'>
            <div style='flex-grow:1'>Proportion of ticket by type</div>
            <div class='hr-line white'></div>
        </div>
        <div>{{currentTypeCategory}}</div>
        <switch-form
        :options='options'
        :smallSelection=false
        @selectedCategory='changeRatioCategory'
        class='option-switch'
        ></switch-form>

    </div>

</div>
```

How can I make the two different '' not share the data in the parent.
I want to use the  component multiple times and I want each to emit its own data so that I can use two different data.

When it's rendered, the view looks like below.
[image]

Left side will use the data from the left switch
while the right side will use the data received from the right switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple things here you should concider fixing:

1. Remove the id - Since you are using the component two times, you will end up with the same id twice. Id attribute should be unique.
2. v-model is essentially the same as `:value` and `@change` combined. This means you ideally should not use `:value`, `@change` is ok to use, but it's not needed. I think in your case, it will be easier to use `:value` and `@change`. Example below.
3. Don't use name here due to it grouping the radios (your initial problem). Again, since you use the component more than once, the
   name will be duplicated. This means that the buttons in the 2nd one
   you spawn will be grouped to the first one with the same name. You
   can look at the name in the same way as an id. You either have to
   create a unique name per component usage (as a prop or using a
   random string) Or simply not use name and rely on `:value`. -
   example below.

```html
<div
    v-if='twoSelection'
    :class="{ 'switch-field' : !smallSelection, 'small-switch-field':smallSelection}"
>
    <input
        type="radio"
        @change="categoryChange"
        :value="options[0] === my first radio value"
    />
    <label for="radio-first">
        {{ options[0].toUpperCase() }}
    </label>
<!-- Note value is the same on both but different conditions - this makes it a "group". -->
    <input
        type="radio"
        @change="categoryChange"
        :value="options[0] === 'my second radio value'"
    />
    <label for="radio-second">{{options[1].toUpperCase()}}</label>
</div>
```

```js
methods:{
    categoryChange(event) {
        // @change provides an event that we can get the changed value with
        this.$emit("selectedCategory", event.target.value);
    }
},
```